# Next.js, TypeScript, ESLint. Compilation - succeeded with errors. Why?

Tags: typescript, next.js, eslint

I'm learning Next.js and have got unexpected results while working with TypeScript and ESLint.

ESLint work fine with TypeScript, but my project compilation - succeeded with errors. So I can't understand why compilation is succeeded with errors.

**Work environment**:

```json
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.15.5",
    "yarn": "1.22.10"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "10.1.3",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^14.14.37",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.3",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.3",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.21.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.21.0",
    "eslint": "^7.24.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "^12.3.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.23.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1",
    "typescript": "^4.2.4"
  }
```

**tsconfig.json**:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "strict": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "ES2017",
    "module": "ESnext",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "lib": ["es6", "dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"]
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

**.eslintrc**:

```json
{
  "root": true,
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "node": true,
    "es6": true
  },
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "project": "./tsconfig.json",
    "ecmaVersion": 2018,
    "codeFrame": true,
    "sourceType": "module",
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    }
  },
  "settings": {
    "react": {
      "version": "detect"
    },
    "import/parsers": {
      "@typescript-eslint/parser": [".ts", ".tsx"]
    },
    "import/resolver": {
      "node": {
        "paths": ["src"],
        "extensions": [".ts", ".tsx"]
      }
    },
    "import/extensions": [".ts", ".tsx"]
  },
  "plugins": ["prettier"],
  "extends": [
    "airbnb-typescript",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "plugin:import/errors",
    "plugin:import/warnings",
    "plugin:import/typescript",
    "prettier"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "react/react-in-jsx-scope": "off",
    "react/jsx-filename-extension": ["error", { "extensions": [".tsx"] }],
    "prettier/prettier": ["error"],
    "@typescript-eslint/no-use-before-define": [
      "error",
      { "functions": false, "classes": false, "variables": true }
    ],
    "max-len": ["error", { "code": 120 }]
  }
}
```

**My file with errors**:

```js
import '../styles/globals.css'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}

export default MyApp
```

**Errors**:

```
Parsing error: "parserOptions.project" has been set for @typescript-eslint/parser.
The file does not match your project config: src\pages\_app.js.
The file must be included in at least one of the projects provided.
```

*I will be grateful for any help. Thanks for your attention.*

Comment: If you're using TypeScript shouldn't your file be `_app.ts`?

Comment: I want the project not to be compiled, if there are errors in it, it doesn't matter what errors.

Answer (score 0):

I understood the reason for the problem.
Need to add some configuration for the next.config.js

**next.config.js**

```js
const LiveReloadPlugin = require('webpack-livereload-plugin')
const ESLintPlugin = require('eslint-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
  future: {
    webpack5: true
  },
  webpack: (config, { buildId, dev, isServer, defaultLoaders, webpack }) => {
    if (dev) config.plugins.push(
      new LiveReloadPlugin({
        port: 2999,
        hostname: 'localhost'
      }),

      new ESLintPlugin({
        extensions: ['ts', 'tsx'],
        failOnError: true
      })
    )

    return config
  }
}
```

and then install devDependencies

```sh
npm i eslint-webpack-plugin webpack-livereload-plugin -D
```